# How can i store a string with quotes in it into a sql db?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a site and the user inputs a title.  I want the title to be able to use any punctuation.  My problem is ill have a query:

```
"INSERT INTO table(title, body) VALUES ('$title','$body')";
```

where $title and $body are GET vars.  What happens it when i put a quote in for the title it acts as if it ends the string and creates and invalid sql query.  Say i have

```
$title = "I'm entering a title";
"INSERT INTO table(title, body) VALUES ('$title','$body')";
//"INSERT INTO table(title, body) VALUES ('I'm entering a title','$body')";
```

It ends the string. I've tried using all double quotes and escape characters but nothing.  Does anyone know a solution?

Comment: Maybe you could use html entities

Comment: Obligatory link: http://bobby-tables.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query is vulnerable with `SQL Injection` but using PHP's **[PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)** or **[MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php)** helps you solve that problem (*also allows you to insert single quotes in the database*), Please read the article below

- [How can I prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection)

Comment: So mysqli and bindparams completely fool proofs sql injections?

Comment: for me, yes. [SQL injection that gets around **mysql_real_escape_string**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)

Answer (score 1):

Use these two functions while entring data to database and out from database.

```
/****************************************/
/* Encode special chars                 */
/*                                      */
/****************************************/

function DBin($string) 
{
    return  trim(htmlspecialchars($string,ENT_QUOTES));
}

/****************************************/
/* Decode special chars                 */
/*                                      */
/****************************************/

function DBout($string) 
{
    $string = trim($string);
    return htmlspecialchars_decode($string,ENT_QUOTES);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should sanitize your variables via PHP first and then send them clean via PDO or MySQLi...

Answer (score 0):

You can try this php function..

```
mysql_real_escape_string

    $title1       = "I'm entering a title";
    $title        = mysqli_real_escape_string($title1);
    "INSERT INTO table(title, body) VALUES ('$title','$body')";
```

Try with this, hope this ll help you...

Comment: [SQL injection that gets around mysql_real_escape_string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)

Comment: do i need this if i am using the mysqli prepare route?  the php manual says it is discouraged for use and mysqli should be used

Comment: wrong!  mysqli_real_escape_string expects 2 parameters

Answer (score 0):

You need to `mysqli_real_escape_string` your SQL.

Answer (score 0):

There is already a built-in method for this situation... have a look in [`mysql_escape_string`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-escape-string.php) method... see the below code...

```
$title = "I'm entering a title";
$title = mysql_escape_string( $title );
// $title === I\'m entering a title
"INSERT INTO table(title, body) VALUES ('$title','$body')";
// "INSERT INTO table(title, body) VALUES ('I\'m entering a title','$body')";
```

Comment: [SQL injection that gets around mysql_real_escape_string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)